# Best way to test controllers in Rails 6 API backend using JWT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jwt, rubygems, rspec-rails

More a generic question as I have read a fair bit and I'm not sure what is best practice. I have a Rails 6 API as my backend for a project.
I have used JWT for authentication. How is the best way to test controller methods that require a user to be logged in?
I have a test and method for my create user method that does not require a person to be logged in, which works via postman and passes the test too.
I've read about using Knock or Devise? But I'm not overly sure! I learned JWT at a Bootcamp but never did testing.
Knock looks like it adds extra layers to the controllers themselves. Is there a way to test JWT authentication of specific controller methods in the request.spec without a gem or is a specific gem best practice / easiest?

I have an authcontroller currently with the code:

```
    class Api::V1::AuthController < ApplicationController

  def login
    user = User.find_by(username: user_login_params[:username])
    debugger
    if user && user.authenticate(user_login_params[:password])
      token = encode_token({ id: user.id })
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(user), jwt: token }
    else
      render json: { message: "invalid name or password" }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def user_login_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

Then the standard has_secure_password on the model. My application controller is where I generate my token.

Say for example I want to test my user index controller method, but you need to be logged in. I know how to write the code and get it working, but not how to generate a test!

Thanks in advance for any help to a novice coder trying to learn! Feel free to ask more questions for clarity!

Comment: Are you currently using Knock or Devise? It sounds like you aren't from the question. Are you using a JWT service, like Auth0? Without knowing a lot of the details your best bet might be to stub the JWT for authenticated routes. If you are using Knock they have some good testing docs from their readme: https://github.com/nsarno/knock#authenticated-tests

Comment: Hi JD,  not using either of those gems yet. Not using Auth0. Just using JWT tokens and passing them to the logged in user if their credentials match match on login. Would you recommend using Devise or Knock? Or is stubbing just the easiest way to do it ? Thanks again!

Comment: Can paste my auth controller if needed!

Comment: Sorry me again. For example would it be this straight forward with Devise?

https://medium.com/uzair-ahmed/how-to-devise-jwt-with-rspec-725f1395a042

But using the request spec not controller spec?

Comment: If you aren't using Knock or Devise then I wouldn't bring them in your app for testing. You will have to stub the JWT, something like what this user posted https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/86h08t/rspec_request_specs_best_practices_stub_auth/dw515lh/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Okay, you're amazing. Thanks so much. Would you suggest for future projects using Knock or Devise as well?

Comment: I think that all depends :). I've used Devise before with several production applications. and I've never used Knock. If I were you, I would investigate those gems and create some dummy apps to find out what you like/dislike about them. Also check out things like usage of the library, how often the library is updated, etc. If you know what features you need ahead of time, make sure the library you use supports it. Hope that helps!